# I get a build error while building my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 52m 55s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         3229.1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

Please how do i fix.

i tried runing this flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-tree-shake-icons but same result, i also tried changing the complesdkversion.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the best things you have to do when encountered issue while building app etc

Do below given steps:

1. **delete .gradle**  (located in Android folder)
2. **Flutter Clean**
3. **Flutter Pub get**

Sometimes you have to delete pupspec.lock file
or also see the stack trace if there are any minimum version SDK restrictions or try to update your **gradle** build version.

Comment: Am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar kind of issue once. So for windows the openJDK platform binary is running in the background so end the task. Then go to .gradle > cache > then delete the folder the error is showing. After these steps the issue was resolved.(Cause of error: The file classes.jar got corrupted for some reason). Thank you.

Comment: Am still getting the error, I don't know why, I have tried everything.